# Get value of Magento custom category attribute in left column

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Ok, Im trying to display the contents of a custom Magento category attribute in the left column of my store page, right at the top.

I am editing 2columns-left.phtm, and inserting the following:

```
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId());
echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getName(), 'name');
```

This is inserted immediately before

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?>
```

Now, before anyone points out the obvious, yes I know this code uses the pre-existing attribute 'name', but I am so tired and foggy I have resorted to simple examples just to try to get it to work. My attribute is category_desc - this has been created and successfully stored via a simple module I have written. Confirmed by adding a value to it in the back end, saving the category and then refreshing - the entered value is successfully saved.

Even the example above will not work - it just renders a completely blank left column. I have also tried countless variations on this and other code I have found (including several posts on SO) which is supposed to allow me access to my nice new custom attribute in the category, but I just cannot get it to work. There must be a way of getting access to this value simply... surely.

I'm usng Magento 1.7. The code used in the module to create the custom attribute is as follows:

config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <SS_CustomCategoryAttribute>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </SS_CustomCategoryAttribute>
</modules>

<global>
    <resources>
        <add_category_attribute>
            <setup>
                <module>SS_CustomCategoryAttribute</module>
                <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </add_category_attribute>
        <add_category_attribute_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </add_category_attribute_write>
        <add_category_attribute_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </add_category_attribute_read>
    </resources>
</global>
```

mysql4-install-0.0.1.php:

```
<?php
$this->startSetup();
$this->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'category_desc', array(
'group'         => 'General',
'input'         => 'textarea',
'type'          => 'text',
'label'         => 'Category Description',
'backend'       => '',
'visible'       => true,
'required'      => false,
'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
'visible_on_front' => true,
'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
));

$this->endSetup();
```

SS_CustomCatgoryAttribute.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <SS_CustomCategoryAttribute>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>community</codePool>
    </SS_CustomCategoryAttribute>
</modules>
</config>
```

In case its not apparent, I am relatively new to this level of Magento customisation, and I must confess to having adapted the module code from another source, but it seems to work well...

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Add function on left layout left_col.phtml

```
 function addAttribute($code)

{
    $this->_getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect($code);

return $this;

}
```

For displaying value of custom attribute in left layout left_col.phtml

```
echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('author_name')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)
```